# How to grocery-crud grid reload without refreshing page

Tags: javascript, ajax, codeigniter, grocery-crud

I am new in grocery-crud,

I have no idea how to reload grocery-crud grid without refreshing page.

Currently i have relaod all page in ajax

```
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url: "<?php echo base_url() ?>user/user_function/"+dash_id,
        success: function(responses) {
            location.reload(); 
        }
    });
```

Any ideas what I need to do to make this work ? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Create a view with grid formatting and load it from method with "return" param = TRUE;

Then, return this content in the response of ajax call and load it into a div:

In view, change the *responses* manipulation:

```
<script>
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url: "<?php echo base_url() ?>user/user_function/"+dash_id,
    success: function(responses) {
        $('#result').html(responses); 
    }
});
</script>

<div id="result"></div>
```

In controller's method, do this:

```
class User extends CI_Controller
{
    public function user_function($dash_id)
    {
        $data_to_grid = array();
        ... // do your code and populate a $data array

        $result = $this->load->view('View_name', $data_to_grid, TRUE);

        header('Content-type: text/html;charset=utf-8');
        echo $result;
        return;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.